# Wall Function not working in my app what's wrong?

Tags: facebook, function, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

This application seems to be working, every thing is fine but not for the wall and invite friends buttons.
 This is my app url: http://apps.facebook.com/mypersonnaldeathage 
and the code of wall function:

```
FB.ui({
     method: 'feed',
     name: '<?= $appname;?>',
     link: '<?= $canvasURL;?>',
     picture: '<?php echo $callBackURL.$appimagename;?>',
     caption: '<?=$wallpub;?>',
     description: '<?= json_encode(strip_tags($line, ''));?>',
     actions: [
     { name: '<?= $walllink;?>', link: '<?= $canvasURL;?>'}
     ],
     message: ''
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You issue lies in the action name not getting filled in

> *action links must have string 'href' and 'text' attributes*

Your code you served to me

```
function publishToWall() {FB.ui({     method: 'feed',     name: 'Your Personal Age Of Death',     link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/persodeathage/',     picture: 'http://www.septimageneracion.net/pdage/gravestone.jpg',     caption: 'How and When Will You Die',     description: '"You have 37 years to live...You will die from excitement when you get an email telling you that you won the Nigerian Lottery. \n"',    actions: [    { name: '', link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/persodeathage/'}  ],  message: ''   },function(response) {     if (response && response.post_id) {       //alert('Post was published.');     } else {       //alert('Post was not published.');     }   } );}
```

Notice the `actions: [    { name: '', link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/persodeathage/'}  ]` part.

Comment: thanks for the support but i'm still confused plzz can i send you the application i'm stuck :(

Comment: You are missing the name parameter,  it is an empty string ''.   Hard code something into it rather than using `<?= $walllink;?>` and see if that helps.